# How to store retrofit2 API responses in an ArrayList and use it to populate recyclerView in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rapidapi

How can I store responses from api to items array and use it latter

```
val items = ArrayList<ConvertedCurrency>()

for(curr in targetCurrencies) {
    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ExchangeRateAPI::class.java)
    val call =
        request.getNewCurrency(etCurr.text.toString(), curr, etAmount.text.toString())

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ConvertedCurrency> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ConvertedCurrency>,
            response: Response<ConvertedCurrency>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                textView.text = response.body()?.new_amount.toString() + response.body()?.new_currency
                val item = response.body() as ConvertedCurrency
                items.add(item) //adding responses to array

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConvertedCurrency>, t: Throwable) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        
    })
}

//I want to use that array here 
recyclerAdapter = CurrencyRecyclerAdapter(items)
currencyRecycler.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    adapter = recyclerAdapter
}
```

When I run this in line where I initialize CurrencyRecyclerAdapter(items) the items array is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enqueue` method is called asynchronously, meaning that the code inside the `enqueue` method will be executed at some point in the future. Which means, you have set the adapter before the items array has been filled.

Try this :

```
val items = ArrayList<ConvertedCurrency>()

for(curr in targetCurrencies) {
    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ExchangeRateAPI::class.java)
    val call =
        request.getNewCurrency(etCurr.text.toString(), curr, etAmount.text.toString())

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ConvertedCurrency> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ConvertedCurrency>,
            response: Response<ConvertedCurrency>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                textView.text = response.body()?.new_amount.toString() + response.body()?.new_currency
                val item = response.body() as ConvertedCurrency
                items.add(item) //adding responses to array

                // Initialize the CurrencyRecyclerAdapter and set it as the adapter for the currencyRecycler view
                recyclerAdapter = CurrencyRecyclerAdapter(items)
                currencyRecycler.apply {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    adapter = recyclerAdapter
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ConvertedCurrency>, t: Throwable) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
}
```